# Java Streams - Get a "symmetric difference list" from two other lists

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Im trying to use Java 8 streams to combine lists.
How can I get a "symmetric difference list" (all object that only exist in one list) from two existing lists.
I know how to get an intersect list and also how to get a union list.

In the code below I want the disjoint Cars from the two lists of cars (bigCarList,smallCarList).
I expect the result to be a list with the 2 cars ("Toyota Corolla" and "Ford Focus")

Example code:

```
public void testDisjointLists() {
    List<Car> bigCarList = get5DefaultCars();
    List<Car> smallCarList = get3DefaultCars();

    //Get cars that exists in both lists
    List<Car> intersect = bigCarList.stream().filter(smallCarList::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Get all cars in both list as one list
    List<Car> union = Stream.concat(bigCarList.stream(), smallCarList.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Get all cars that only exist in one list
    //List<Car> disjoint = ???

}

public List<Car> get5DefaultCars() {
    List<Car> cars = get3DefaultCars();
    cars.add(new Car("Toyota Corolla", 2008));
    cars.add(new Car("Ford Focus", 2010));
    return cars;
}

public List<Car> get3DefaultCars() {
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    cars.add(new Car("Volvo V70", 1990));
    cars.add(new Car("BMW I3", 1999));
    cars.add(new Car("Audi A3", 2005));
    return cars;
}

class Car {
    private int releaseYear;
    private String name;
    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Car(String name, int releaseYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    //Overridden equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Comment: `List<Car> disjoint = bigCarList;` ? I don't really understand the question. You have two lists A and B, and you want all the elements of the list A. So, just use A. Please clarify.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the *symmetric difference* of the lists.

Comment: Yes i looking for the Symmetric difference. Sorry to fool you all by my bad english.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your own code, there is a straight-forward solution:

```
List<Car> disjoint = Stream.concat(
    bigCarList.stream().filter(c->!smallCarList.contains(c)),
    smallCarList.stream().filter(c->!bigCarList.contains(c))
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just filter one list for all items not contained in the other and vice versa and concatenate both results. That works fairly well for small lists and before consider optimized solutions like hashing or making the result `distinct()` you should ask yourself why you are using lists if you don’t want neither, duplicates nor a specific order.

It seems like you actually want `Set`s, not `List`s. If you use `Set`s, [Tagir Valeev’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074919/2711488) is appropriate. But it is not working with the actual semantics of `List`s, i.e. doesn’t work if the source lists contain duplicates.

---

But if you are using `Set`s, the code can be even simpler:

```
Set<Car> disjoint = Stream.concat(bigCarSet.stream(), smallCarSet.stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), t->true, (a,b)->null))
  .keySet();
```

This uses the `toMap` collector which creates a `Map` (the value is irrelevant, we simply map to `true` here) and uses a merge function to handle duplicates. Since for two sets, duplicates can only occur when an item is contained in both sets, these are the items we want remove.

The [documentation of `Collectors.toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) says that the merge function is treated “as supplied to [`Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)” and we can learn from there, that simply mapping the duplicate pair to `null` will remove the entry.

So afterwards, the `keySet()` of the map contains the disjoint set.

Comment: @Holger NICE!!! I did not notice that part in the documentation: *.. or removes it if the result is null*. awesome

Answer (score 6):

Something like this may work:

```
Stream.concat(bigCarList.stream(), smallCarList.stream())
      .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(1L))
      .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
      .collect(toList());
```

Here we first collect all the cars to the `Map<Car, Long>` where value is the number of such cars encountered. After that, we `filter` this `Map` leaving only cars that are encountered exactly once, drop the counts and collect to the final `List`.

Comment: This doesn’t work if the source lists contain duplicates. But I think that is rather an issue of the question’s precondition as the OP seem to actually want `Set`s. But when using `Set`s, the solution can be [even simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077178/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger I reached it with a similar question for `Stream`s rather than the `List`s. I think adding up `.distinct()` to each substream could help, *but* thought over the performance strikes me for the stateful nature (Just thinking loud, haven't really thought through yet.)

Comment: The question I was referring to and I made an answer to is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964092/how-to-check-if-two-streams-are-disjoint/64965550#64965550), in case you find additional information elaborate and coupled with the stream approach.

Answer (score 0):

#### A little bit math

*disjoint = A and B are disjoint if their intersect is empty.*

A disjoint is not a set, it is an indicator showing if two sets are disjoint or not. From your description I think you where searching the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

#### Symmetric Difference

But anyhow, if you only want to collect to new Lists then all you need is a collector.

I made a method that creates an Collector. This Collector only "collects" values, where the predicate is evaluated to true. So if you are searching for the symmetric difference, than you only need a predicate.

```
  public void testDisjointLists() {
    List<Car> bigCarList = get5DefaultCars();
    List<Car> smallCarList = get3DefaultCars();

    Collector<Car, ArrayList<Car>, ArrayList<Car>> inter
        = produceCollector(car -> {
          return bigCarList.contains(car) && smallCarList.contains(car);
        });

    Collector<Car, ArrayList<Car>, ArrayList<Car>> symDiff
        = produceCollector(car -> {
          return bigCarList.contains(car) ^ smallCarList.contains(car);
        });

    //Get all cars in both list as one list
    List<Car> union
        = Stream.concat(bigCarList.stream(), smallCarList.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Car> intersect = union.stream().collect(inter);

    //Get all cars that only exist not exists in both Lists
    List<Car> symmetricDifference = union.stream().collect(symDiff);

    System.out.println("Union Cars:");
    union.stream().forEach(car -> System.out.println("Car: " + car));
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Intersect Cars: ");
    intersect.stream().forEach(car -> System.out.println("Car: " + car));
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Symmetric Difference: ");
    symmetricDifference.stream().forEach(car -> System.out.println("Car: " + car));
    System.out.println("");
  }

  public Collector<Car, ArrayList<Car>, ArrayList<Car>> produceCollector(Predicate<Car> predicate) {
    Collector<Car, ArrayList<Car>, ArrayList<Car>> collector = Collector.of(
        ArrayList::new,
        (al, car) -> {
          if (predicate.test(car)) {
            al.add(car);
          }
        },
        (al1, al2) -> {
          al1.addAll(al2);
          return al1;
        }
    );
    return collector;
  }
```

### For performance freaks

After doing some research, it seems that the collector is about 14 times faster than a first filter solution.

```
long before2 = System.nanoTime();
List<Car> intersect2 = union.stream().filter(car -> {
  return bigCarList.contains(car) && smallCarList.contains(car);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
long after2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Time for first filter solution: " + (after2 - before2));


long before = System.nanoTime();
List<Car> intersect = union.stream().collect(inter);
long after = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Time for collector solution: " + (after - before));
```

Time for first filter solution: 540906

Time for collector solution: 37543

Comment: Your `symmetricDifference` isn’t symmetric; it doesn’t accept cars of the `smallCarList` not contained in the `bigCarList`. You can use `bigCarList.contains(car) ^ smallCarList.contains(car)` to solve this. By the way, there is no need for the `intersect` operation to test whether `car` is contained in `bigCarList` when you stream over `bigCarList`. That redundant test can be omitted.

Comment: There is only one remark left. While it might be a good exercise to write a custom `Collector` (but you shouldn’t ignore type safety, `ArrayList` without type arguments is a *raw type*), there is no benefit here. A `.filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())` on a stream would do as well. It’s not the intended use of the stream API to move all intermediate steps into the collector…

Comment: Alternatively you could turn `produceCollector` into a generic method as the collector can collect arbitrary items.

Comment: I was thinking about a generic solution, but for this example I thought it is much easier.

Comment: It’s actually very easy. Just replace all occurrences of `Car` at the declaration and inside of `produceCollector` with `T` and place a single `<T>` right before the return type. That’s all. If you are using an IDE, it’s even easier. Just place a `<Car>` right before the return type, then tell the IDE to rename that type parameter to `T` (technically, that renaming is not necessary but having a type parameter with the same name as a concrete class is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, albeit not as elegant as one line streams:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> y = new HashMap<>();
    bigCarSet ().forEach(i -> y.put(i, !y.containsKey(i)));
    bigCarList().forEach(i -> y.put(i, !y.containsKey(i)));
    y.entrySet().stream().filter(Map.Entry::getValue).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which can be simplified to at least:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> y = new HashMap<>();
    Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).forEach(i -> y.put(i, !y.containsKey(i)));
    y.entrySet().stream().filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking for the symmetric difference. And the symmetric difference can be expressed as:

1. Either the difference between the union and the intersection:

   A △ B = (A ∪ B) - (B ∩ A)
2. Or the union of the differences:

   A △ B = (A – B) ∪ (B – A)

The first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077178/1876620) achieves it by #2, while the second part achieves it by #1. Here I'll show a variation of approach #1:

```
List<Car> result = new ArrayList<>(bigCarList);
result.addAll(smallCarList); // (A ∪ B)

result.removeIf(c -> bigCarList.contains(c) && smallCarList.contains(c)); // (B ∩ A)
```

This can be optimized if lists are converted to sets, so that using `contains` is `O(1)`:

```
List<Car> bigCarList = get5DefaultCars();
List<Car> smallCarList = get3DefaultCars();

Set<Car> bigCarSet = new HashSet<>(bigCarList);
Set<Car> smallCarSet = new HashSet<>(smallCarList);

Set<Car> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(bigCarList);
result.addAll(smallCarList); // (A ∪ B)

result.removeIf(c -> bigCarSet.contains(c) && smallCarSet.contains(c)); // (B ∩ A)
```

Answer (score 0):

*the lambda solution with* `groupingBy`*:*
the map values with the `true`-key are in both lists
the map values with the `false`-key are disjoint

```
Map<Boolean,List<Car>> map = Stream.concat(bigCarList.stream(),
    smallCarList.stream()).collect(
        groupingBy( b -> bigCarList.stream().anyMatch( s -> b.equals( s ) )
            && smallCarList.stream().anyMatch( s -> b.equals( s ) ) ) );
List<Car> disjoint = map.get( false );  // [Toyota Corolla, Ford Focus]
```

*same principle but shorter w/o inline streams:*

```
Map<Boolean,List<Car>> map = Stream.concat(bigCarList.stream(),
    smallCarList.stream()).collect(
        groupingBy( b -> bigCarList.contains( b )
            && smallCarList.contains( b ) ) );
List<Car> disjoint = map.get( false );  // [Toyota Corolla, Ford Focus]
```

*both are working with duplicates as well*
*means: duplicates in one list that are not contained in the other list*
If the amount of data is not so huge that you are running into disk space issues, a simple `groupingBy` ‑ without filtering or additional queries to reduce the result set ‑ should be the clearest and fastest solution.